# Namespaces, types and the using directive-in header file same type is recognized as field and function return value types but not as parameter types

Tags: c++, visual-c++

For a simple game, I have the following classes:

```
// color.h
#ifndef COLOR_H
#define COLOR_H
#include "ns.h"
BEGIN_NS
enum class color {
    white,
    black
};
END_NS
#endif
```

and

```
// position.h
#ifndef POSITION_H
#define POSITION_H
#include <string>
#include "ns.h"
BEGIN_NS
struct position {
    int rank, file;                     // The rank and file
public:
    std::string code() const;
    bool valid() const {
        return rank >= 0 && rank < ranks && file >= 0 && file < files;
    }
    bool at(int r, int f) const { return rank == r && file == f; }
    bool at(const position &p) const { return rank == p.rank && file == p.file; }
public:
    static position from_code(std::string code);
};
END_NS
#endif
```

and, finally

```
#ifndef PIECE_H
#define PIECE_H
#include <string>
#include "color.h"
#include "position.h"
BEGIN_NS
class board;
class piece {
protected:
    piece(const std::string& type, color c, const position &start_pos);
    const color _color;                 // The color of the piece
    const position _start_pos;          // The initial starting position of this piece
    position _pos;                      // The current position of the piece
    int _times_moved;                   // The number of times the piece was moved
    bool _captured;                     // Defines whether the piece has been captured
    const std::string _type;            // Defines the type of piece
public:
    const position& start() const { return _start_pos; }
    const position& position() const { return _pos; }
    color color() const { return _color; }
    bool captured() const { return _captured; }
    int moved() const { return _times_moved; }
    bool enemy_of(const piece* p) const { return p && p->color() != _color; }
    bool ally_of(const piece* p) const { return p && p->color() == _color; }
    void capture() { _captured = true; }
    virtual piece* eval(const board* board, const position &pos) const = 0;
};
END_NS
#endif
```

Also, the namespace macros are defined in ns.h:

```
#define BEGIN_NS namespace chess_game {
#define END_NS }
```

The problem is with the position structure usage in my piece.h file, specifically at the virtual piece* eval(...) function. The compiler cannot resolve position as a valid type, but it does not complain about position being used as a constructor arg, as two of the field types and as a return type to the start() and position() functions. Specifically, the compiler says:

IntelliSense function "chess_game::piece::position" is not a type name
C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note C++ does not support default int
C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'

The position parameter type in the eval function prototype is underlined, but none of the other usages of the type are underlined. If I fully qualify *just that* instance of position with my namespace using scope resolution, then the error goes away. If I remove just the eval function from the class, the error goes away. Why would it require the type to be fully qualified in the function parameter signature and not anywhere else in the class? Qualifying the parameter type with the namespace isn't a big deal, I just wish to know why I have to and what the problem is...

Visual Studio 2013 C++ compiler

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Using `BEGIN_NS` and `END_NS` is a terrible idea.

Comment: I'll pass that along to P.J. Plauger

Comment: I don't see any using directive involved here (which is probably a good thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class piece {
    // ...
    const position& position() const { return _pos; }
    // ...
```

The member function `chess_game::piece::position() const` *hides* the type `chess_game::position()` in the scope of `piece`.  After that member function has been declared, you can no longer use just `position` to refer to the class.

Avoid using the same name for a type and a function.

Comment: I would of never, ever, ever thought of that. Thanks a bunch

Comment: This answer neglects to mention the solution, if you don't want to rename anything.  Just say `chess_game::position` to refer to the class, and `position` to mean the member function.